# Changing text color in Attributed TextView (Xcode)

Tags: ios, xcode, textview

I am trying to change the color of a sentence in my TextView which is attributed.  How do I go about this?

Say, I wanted to change the color of the first sentence to red.

[image]

When I click these buttons (the left is "Text Color" and the other is "Background Color") nothing happens.
[image]

Comment: I feel like an idiot.  Just had to click the T Calendar looking icon, which popped up a panel where you can edit these.

Comment: Do you fancy doing it programatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by doing it programatically. Use `NSMutableAttributedString`

```
NSMutableAttributedString *stringText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"This is awesome"];
//Green color for the first four characters.
[stringText addAttribute: NSForegroundColorAttributeName value: [UIColor greenColor] range: NSMakeRange(0, 4)];
// Sets the font color of last four characters to yellow.
[stringText addAttribute: NSForegroundColorAttributeName value: [UIColor yellowColor] range: NSMakeRange(14, 10)];
```

Set this text to your UITextView. It should work. Also make sure if text changes dynamically you need to care full with NSMakeRange.

Comment: Didn't need to do it programmatically but thanks anyways.

Comment: Yeah i know but once you started doing it programtically you will start loving it. I was like you while starting ios development.

Comment: Agreed.  But I do have to say it is redundant doing it programmatically when it could be easily achieved with Xcode's interface.